# Lebesgue outer measure using open balls- help with proof

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

This question has been asked before but the solutions use a version of Vitali Covering Lemma which is not clear to me how it relates to the statement I am familiar with (below). Any help is appreciated.

The problem:

> For every Lebesgue measurable set $E$ we have that $$m(E)= \inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty m(B_i): B_i\mbox{ are balls, } E\subset \cup_{i=1}^\infty B_i\right\}.$$

For the proof, we use Vitali Covering Thm:

> Let $E\subset \mathbb R^n$ be Lebesgue measurable with $m(E)<\infty$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a covering of $E$ such that for any $x\in E$ and any $\delta<0$ there exists a ball centered at $x$ and of diameter $\delta$ in $\mathcal C$. Then, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is a finite disjoint sub-collection $B_1,\dots, B_N$ of $\mathcal C$ such that $m(E\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^N B_i)<\varepsilon$.

Fix $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. If $m(E)<\infty$, we apply Vitali Covering Thm: Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a collection of balls centered at any $x\in E$ and of any positive diameter $\delta>0$. Then, take a sequence $\varepsilon_k>0$ which approaches $0$ as $k\to \infty$. Then, by Vitali covering theorem, for each $\varepsilon_k$ there exists a finite disjoint subcollection $B^k_1,\dots,B^k_{N_k}$ of $\mathcal C$ such that
$$m(E\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^{N_k}B_i^k)<\varepsilon_k.$$ Call $F_k:= E\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^{N_k}B_i^k.$ Since 
$E\subset F_k\cup \bigcup_{i=1}^{N_k}B_i^k,$ by monotonicity and subadditivity of measures, we get that

$$m(E)\leq m(F_k)+ m(\bigcup_{i=1}^{N_k}B_i^k).$$

Then, as $k\to\infty$, we get that $m(E)\leq m(\cap_{k=1}^\infty\bigcup_{i=1}^{N_k}B_i^k)$ and $m(F_k)\to0$.

From here:

- I don't know how to make an open cover of $E$ using balls $B_i^k$ and their union and intersection; as in the problem.
- I also don't know how to deal with $m(E)= \infty$.
- Lastly, I don't know how to do the other direction. Perhaps a regularity result about Lebesgue measure would help (Theorem 2.40 from Folland) but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

- Lastly, I don't know how to do the other direction. Perhaps a regularity result about Lebesgue measure would help (Theorem 2.40 from Folland) but I don't know how.

There are certainly collections of balls with $E$ as a subset of their union. $B_n = \{x: \|x - 0\| < n\}$, for example. So the set is not empty. Further, since $A \subseteq C \implies m(A) \le m(C)$, we know that $m(E) \le m\left(\bigcup_n B_n\right) \le \sum_n m(B_n)$ for any such collection $\{B_n\}_n$. So the set is bounded below by $m(E)$. Thus the infimum exists and is $\ge m(E)$.

> - I also don't know how to deal with $m(E)= \infty$.

Well, that is easy enough. $m(E)$ is a lower bound of values in the set, and $\infty$ is an upper bound of any set of non-negative extended-real numbers. So if the two are the same...

> - I don't know how to make an open cover of $E$ using balls $B_i^k$ and    their union and intersection; as in the problem.

The purpose of the Vitali Covering Lemma proof is to show that there are collections of balls whose total measure exceeds that of $E$ by arbitrarily small amounts, meaning the infimum cannot be larger than $m(E)$. However, there are parts missing from the argument as you've reproduced it. "$m(E)\leq m(\cap_{k=1}^\infty\bigcup_{i=1}^{N_k}B_i^k)$", heads off in a different direction than you need. Intersections of unions of balls are not unions of balls.

Personally, I think I would try to prove it directly from the definition of outer measure. But that depends on what definition you are using, so I cannot say how to do it in your case. I would note that $n$-cubes are contained in balls the ratio of whose measure to that of the $n$-cube is some fixed factor $M$. For each $\epsilon > 0$, cover $E$ with such $n$-cubes whose total measure is $< m(E) + \epsilon / M$, then replace each of those cubes with its circumferencing ball to get a collection of balls covering $E$ whose measure $< m(E) + \epsilon$.